# Run the Windows Service with User Name & Password

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm writing the windows form program to monitor our in-house windows services.
The screenshot is provided for the draft version of that program.
[image]

What I want to do is... I want to pass UserName & Password to run the services from my program.  I don't know which class or components to use.

I tried to use the following codes, as we used in Installing the services.  However, it does not still work.  Perhaps, I don't know how to bind the user credential with service controller.

```
ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
            serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.User;
            serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = txtPassword.Text;
            serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = txtUserName.Text;
```

So, Please advise me how could I achieve my requirements?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this library which lets you do just that:

[Install a Windows Service in a smart way instead of using the Windows Installer MSI package](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DynWinServiceInstallUtil.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to manipulate the account that an existing, installed service is running under, you will need to use the code specified in the following article:

http://weblogs.asp.net/avnerk/archive/2007/05/08/setting-windows-service-account-c-and-wmi.aspx

Basically, the author found that it wasn't as simple as expected but it was possible (without a registry modification).